# How do you trigger a promise to resolve in an Angular test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

```
if (isPromise(self.parentId)) {
  console.log('DEBUG: outside then');
  self.parentId.then(function (parent) {
    console.log('DEBUG: inside then');
    self.parentId = parent.id;
    self.notes = Note.query({
      parent_type: self.parentType,
      parent_id: self.parentId,
    });
  });
```

I want to test that `Note.query` gets called when `self.parentId` is a `promise`.

```
it('when a promise is passed in', function () {
  $controller('NotesController', {}, {
    parentId: Lead.get({ id: 1 }).$promise,
    parentType: 'leads',
  });
  expect(Note.query.called).to.equal(true);
});
```

This doesn't work. The outer log happens, but the inner one does not. So presumably, the problem is that the promise isn't resolving.

1) Why doesn't this work?
2) How can I get it working?

Answer (score 0):

For testing out promises you need to create spy on your promise returning function. Then resolve the promise with some mock data.
Inject $q in test first.

```
deferred = _$q.defer();
spyOn(self, 'parentId').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
deferred.resolve({ id: 102 });
$scope.$apply();
```

This should resolve your promise. Change field names as per your requirement it was just sample

Comment: Including a link to relevant information is not nearly as good as including the relevant information in your answer. External links can, and often do, go down or change their structure so that the information is no longer available.